# Returning grades to the students using google classroom api

Tags: api, google-classroom

Is it possible to set the grades using the google classroom api ? If so please give the steps in detail.

I have tried doing this using courses.coursework.studentSubmission.return but this only updates the state but doesn't return the grade to the student as if a teacher manually grades and returns.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Classroom API, the [StudentSubmission](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions) resource has two fields to store grades: assignedGrade, which is the grade reported to students, and draftGrade, which is a tentative grade visible only to teachers. These fields are updated using courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch with a field mask containing the appropriate fields

For more information, check this [Classroom Help](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020294?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).